# Branching/merging with tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I have created a branch using tortoise svn. I switched to that branch . Now i would like to pull/merge some specific fixes that have been pushed to trunk but have not yet been imported to branch.

I used the option to merge revisions by range. It goes through fine but when I look at the logs, I see that the code is still at a level where it was branched from. I dont see any difference after the merge. Not sure what's going wrong here. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A merge applies the changes to your working copy. Examining the logs won't show anything.
Only when you commit the merged changes, then you will see something in the logs.

Comment: i read the tortoise svn docs but could not find any point using which i can over come this. Being a release engineer, I cannot go ahead and commit files, Is it possible to merge and autocommit the merged revisions?